# Fetch data between morning and evening

Tags: mysql

im trying to fetch the data between two times, i.e., morning (7:30AM to 7:30PM) evening (7:30PM to 7:30AM).
required only hour based output.{ > 7:30 < 19:30 as morning  and > 19:30 < 7:30 as night)

Please suggest the query

```
Tablename: data
----------------
created_date     services_name   id
28-08-2022 18:54    KANE         1
28-08-2022 19:00    BAPLO        2
28-08-2022 23:22    BAPLO        3
28-08-2022 23:40    VLOTLS       4
29-08-2022 00:02    DELLP        5
29-08-2022 00:42    SECON        6
29-08-2022 02:00    BAPLO        7
29-08-2022 03:00    PRODC        8
29-08-2022 05:14    DELLP        9
29-08-2022 05:30    SECON        10
29-08-2022 05:42    SECON        11
```

im using below command to fetch output

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT( HOUR(created_date),  ' to ', CONCAT( HOUR(created_date), ':59:59' ) ) as time_frame,
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  data
GROUP BY 
  DATE(created_date), 
  HOUR(created_date)
ORDER BY
  DATE(created_date), 
  HOUR(created_date)
```

Out as below

```
0 to 0:59:59    2
2 to 2:59:59    1
3 to 3:59:59    1
5 to 5:59:59    3
18 to 18:59:59  1
19 to 19:59:59  1
23 to 23:59:59  2
```

But i required as

morning ( between 07:30 to 19:30)  count is 2
evening ( between 19:30 to 07:30)  count is 9

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: `SELECT 
  CONCAT( HOUR(created_date),  ' to ', CONCAT( HOUR(created_date), ':59:59' ) ) as time_frame,
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  data
GROUP BY 
  DATE(created_date), 
  HOUR(created_date)
ORDER BY
  DATE(created_date), 
  HOUR(created_date)`

Im using this command to get details...
`0 to 0:59:59  22
1 to 1:59:59  6
2 to 2:59:59  24
3 to 3:59:59  12`

Comment: i have edited Question, please check once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a `UNION` to get two separate counts, one for *morning* times and one *evening* times. Within the `WHERE` clause, you can convert `created_date` to a time format using the `TIME()` data type and then plug in your *morning* and *evening* times within the `BETWEEN` condition.

Note that you have to use the `NOT` operator to negate the `BETWEEN` operator for the *evening* count because `BETWEEN` works within a range (small to large `0..1`, not large to small `1..0`) so the `NOT` operator will essentially get everything else outside of the *morning* `BETWEEN` range.

```
SELECT 'Morning' as time_frame, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM temp 
         WHERE TIME(created_date)  
         BETWEEN '07:30:00' AND '19:30:00'
UNION
SELECT 'Evening' as time_frame, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM temp 
         WHERE TIME(created_date)  
         NOT BETWEEN '07:30:00' AND '19:30:00'
```

Output:

| time_frame | count |
| --- | --- |
| Morning | 2 |
| Evening | 9 |

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ae2ec0d96d8afd02e5880a514df39d8).